# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, monogame

I want to load a shader in a Monogame Windows Phone 8 project, but I always get the following error message in this line:

```
BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Effect1.mgfxo"));
```

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

What is wrong? How can I load the file?

My project: http://speedy.sh/CHVbj/GameName1.rar

My code:

```
#if RESOURCEFILES
    BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(@"..\\..\\..\\Content\\Effect1.mgfxo", FileMode.Open));
#else
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Effect1.mgfxo"));
#endif
    distortionEffect = new Effect(GraphicsDevice, Reader.ReadBytes((int)Reader.BaseStream.Length));
```

Comment: Well *is* `Effect1.mgfxo` an embedded resource or not? If it is, are you sure it's embedded at the root? Look at `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames` to check.

Comment: I have a folder named Content in my project, and Effect1.mgfxo is in that folder.

Comment: Well have you used Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames as I suggested?

Comment: How can I use it? What should I do?

Comment: Call it, and look at what it returns. Check whether your resource is in there, and if it is, whether it has a different name (e.g. `Content.Effect1.mgfxo`)

Comment: I can't find a bug. I uploaded my project here if someone wants to take a look: http://speedy.sh/CHVbj/GameName1.rar

Comment: Well that hasn't told us what happened when you tried my suggestion...

Comment: I executed this line: BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Effect1.mgfxo")); But I couldn't find the value of Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames.

Comment: what do you mean by "couldn't find the value"? Did it not compile?